# I want to build asp.net mvc app and I do not want to depend on ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table named country and it have a 3 Columns :

```
ID: generated primary key
Country_Code : not primary key but it is Unique and in most of the time I will
use it Instead of ID.
Country_Name : the long name of the country
```

I can not change any thing from above , it is business requirement.

I used asp.net mvc to generated CURD functionality then I changed the code so that it depend on Country_Code instead of ID so fro example My detail page url look like this:

```
something.com/country/detail/ss
```

I success in read , write and delete but in edit I failed to pass the validation  statement (ModelState.IsValid) the problem is that when data come from my edit page  ID always is 0.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets?

Comment: What does the controller action look like? What does the route table look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a HiddenFor to save the ID when post it to controller.